# How to clear the rest of the backstack from login to an activity which is not root?

Tags: android, back

How to clear the rest of the backstack from login to an activity which is not root?

[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, but from what I can understand, I think you will have to read about, `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`. Refer the official docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: that would clear everything and make Page 1 the new root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

For Login back to Page 1

- add the flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP so that everything above Page 1 gets removed from the back stack
- then I needed to call finish() at Login so that it gets removed from the back stack

I do have other concerns but was able to resolve it, I'm adding it here just in case.

1. Going back to home, I added the flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
2. Going back to fragment and re-opening the selected tab, I used shared preference to record which tab to open, then at the activity where the fragment is I used onResume to check the saved shared preference to set the right tab.
3. For opening a new intent which is not included in the back stack, I called the intent which should come before that new intent with an extra, I used that extra to open the new intent. Not sure if this is the right way to do it but it works.